# Box with text that catches some of the image and displays over it

Tags: html, css

I am looking to display a box with a text over the image, aligning it vertically, but the tricky bit is to have only a part of the box over the image and the rest outside it.

Here's the visual representation of what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: what have you tried? can you show us your codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position: absolute` for text.

HTML:

```
<div class="img">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
}
```

Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/Sa1m0n/pen/vYGdOaN. You can play with it manipulating `left` property for `.text`.

Alternatively, you can always use CSS Grid.